# Programmatically change AcceptButton property and trigger ButtonClickEvent inside a KeyPress event

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: page layout]

I have a page with two independent forms; users would only ever fill out and submit one or the other. When the user presses enter, I would like to trigger the click event of the button of the form that currently has focus. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need two forms?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger Button click using `.PerformClick()` method on `KeyPress` event of the `TextBox` after verifying whether pressed key is `Enter`

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if pressed key is `Enter` key
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return){
         button1.PerformClick();
    }
}
```